# TN Visa Expiring Before Lock Down Restrictions Lifted

Tags: tn-visa

I am a Canadian citizen with a TN visa expiring next month. I was planning to apply for extension in person at border crossing but it does not look like current Covid shelter in place laws will be lifted before my visa expires. Will I be penalized if I let my visa expire before trying to apply for extension?

Comment: Which shelter-in-place rules are preventing you from reentering at the border?